# validation message still existing after enter text using SendKeys in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Validation message is still existing after entering text using `sendkeys`.

Ex:

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//input[@id='UserID'])[3]")).SendKeys("erwrwrwrwer vvv");
```

Comment: Which message ? where exist ? where you are entering text ?

Comment: @ManishSharma Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: It's possible that your field validation is triggered by the onBlur event. Try focusing on another field after using SendKeys.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to replace `FindElement` with `findElement`, `XPath` with `xpath` and `SendKeys` with `sendKeys`.

You can replace following code with your code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='UserID'])[3]")).sendKeys("erwrwrwrwer vvv");
```

I have also observed that you are directly using `webDriver.findElement`

I think first you need to create driver as follows :

```
WebDriver driver ;
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think he's using C#.